# Permission denied to copy or paste files in the system folders

Tags: permissions

Problem Statement:

Well I have installed Xampp 1.8.1 in my Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit system. But I couldn't paste my web files to the `/opt/lampp` directory where `lampp` is installed. As I try to paste my web files to that directory the paste option is greyed out. And while I try pasting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> command the 'Permission denied' error occurs.
Help me out as I am a noobhead in this Linux world!

Comment: While one answer is: "gksudo nautilus", this is not a duplicate of "how can I save a file from gedit" or "how can I avoid write permissions when editing files". I came here because I cannot copy and paste in Nautilus. It does not even have the common decency to offer a one time sudo with password so I have to go to a command line and then come back. I can see linking from the other two questions to here if the answer is, edit in a writeable directory and then use gksudo nautilus to move the files to the real destination. But their correct answers are "gksudo gedit" and "use symbolic links".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter

```
gksudo nautilus
```

This will run the file manager in super user mode.

Comment: it may work but i did not get command meaning. what is nautilus?, why gksudo and why why not sudo?

Comment: Nautilus is the gnome file manager - you could use which you prefer. gksudo is the graphical version of sudo.

Comment: I am dabbling into Linux from Windows.  Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Hi, you did not answer the question of why gksudo not sudo. In my case both work and looks like same result.

Comment: You can also use `su`. `GKSU` ist just a graphical interface.

Comment: `sudo nautilus` worked for me. Thanks.