# Unable to move or copy files from partition to other due to permission issue

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, format, copy

I do have 3 partitions in my hard drive the first one contains boot files while other partitions are empty. While trying to copy file from usb drive to the empty hard drives it showed this **"The folder “xyz” cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination."** what should I do to fix it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/303796/permission-denied-to-copy-or-paste-files-in-the-system-folders

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you issued the copy command as a non-root user. So either become **root** user beforehand (sudo su -) or use something like **sudo cp ...**