# Unable to move folders in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions

Whenever I try to copy a folder into another folder, I get this error: Error while moving “apc”. Permission denied.

I tried using "gksudo nautilus", but my desktop does not display any of the available folders. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: did you try doing `sudo cp -r [nameOfFolder] [nameOfDirectory]`

Comment: What do you mean by, *"my desktop does not display any of the available folders"* ? When you use `gksudo nautilus`, it uses root's home DIR, which is different from your home DIR.

Comment: True that. Try doing `ls -a' to see if your folder is hidden

Comment: Also, might be a duplicate of [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/303796/permission-denied-to-copy-or-paste-files-in-the-system-folders?rq=1[link]

Comment: Can you please open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and run `ls -ld /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY` twice, once with the source directory you want to copy and once with the target directory inside which the copy should be stored. Then [edit] your question and paste the output there in plain text (ideally code-formatted). Thanks.